# how to get the list of contacts that are associated for an events

Tags: event, shared-activities

**hi all
 i have created an event with multiple contacts
 and then
when i was trying to get the list contacts that are associated with an event
in SOQL
the result only first contact is returning
i.e**

```
Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();

for(Event e : [select subject,whoid from event where createdate = TODAY()])
{
  contactIds.Add(e.WhoID);
}

List<Contact> cons = [select Id, Name from Contact where ID IN : contactIds];
sytem.debug(cons)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's by design - the `WhoId` always shows a single, primary relationship on the Event (or Task).

To get all associated contacts, you need to query the [`EventWhoRelation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventwhorelation.htm) object, a junction between Event and Contact. You'd filter on `EventId` to get the relations for one or more specific Events.

Note however that `EventWhoRelation` doesn't necessarily point to a Contact (it could be a Lead, for example), but you can look at the `Type` field to tell the difference.